# Bin patching Arm7tdmi CRC32?

Tags: arm, crc, binary-editing

Ok so I am total noob here. I wanted to play with the bin from an instrument cluster I work on a lot. I was able to pull the bin off the MCU with a J-link. If I erase the chip and flash it with a bin from it or another cluster it works but if I change anything in the bin it won't work.. Don't worry I am not messing with the Odo value thats stored on an EEprom and easy to change lol.

Learned a little about bin patching via youtube/google and ran the bin through binwalk. doing  that binwalk says

> Decimal: 211720  HEX:0x33b08 Description: crc32.

I'm guessing this CRC not matching is making it fail to boot. If I look at the bin with HxD I don't see anything that matches what Binwalk is saying but I am probably looking at it wrong. Where do I find the CRC in this bin from what address is this crc checking because if I use HxD or online CRC generators It doesnt match anything in the bin also...

I am sure I am not describing this all correctly I am still learning and climbing mt. stupid.

All I want to do is change some of the error messages to say something funny. I am just doing this for the novelty and to learn something new.

Linked Github with the bin, [Github link](https://github.com/garnerm91/07-14-GM-cluster-BINs)

BTW all edits I make are one for one changes so I am not shifting anything around in the bin. The attached is unedited and works.

Comment: So I think it sitting at `00012010 08 3B 03` now I am just not sure what section of the file it made for. If you make one for the whole file you get `98BFF3C6`